# WebStorm auto-complete for CSS is not working?

Tags: css, autocomplete, frontend, webstorm

WebStorm auto complete is working fine for everything else except css files.

Comment: check your input source, WS will not working well if you are turning on an input source like iBus.

Comment: I checked already

Comment: Hmm the most common way is reinstall WS or report this bug for intelliJ https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new

Comment: Please check that *.css is correctly associated with CSS in Preferences | Editor | File Types.